# ms access query to oracle via odbc

Tags: oracle, ms-access, plsql

I want to execute oracle function from ms access:
this query works perfect:

```
Select * from table(rpt_0257_ArtEtk_fn('1','1'));
```

this one too:

```
Select * from table(rpt_0257_ArtEtk_fn('Forms!Form1!Text12', '1'));
```

but this one

```
Select * from table(rpt_0257_ArtEtk_fn('Forms!Form1!Text12', 'Forms!Form1!Text12'));
```

and this:

```
Select * from table(rpt_0257_ArtEtk_fn('1', 'Forms!Form1!Text12'));
```

results to "ORA-01722: invalid number"

I do not understand where is the problem.

Comment: Can you provide us with the code of rpt_0257_ArtEtk_fn? I assume that 'Forms!Form1!Text12' is passed as a text value rather than a number.

Comment: No, I dont have access to source code of this function.

Comment: How is the second parameter to `rpt_0257_ArtEtk_fn` declared?  I'm guessing it's a `NUMBER`, but in the calls which fail you're passing in a string which can't be converted to a `NUMBER`.

Comment: Yes, you are wright, first parameter is string, second is number.

Comment: And I assume this is a [PASS THROUGH] query. Correct?

Comment: Yes. this is "Pass trhrough"

Answer (score 0):

try use Val function, for example:

```
Select * from table(rpt_0257_ArtEtk_fn('Forms!Form1!Text12', 'Val(Forms!Form1!Text12)'));
```

or to_number:

```
Select * from table(rpt_0257_ArtEtk_fn('Forms!Form1!Text12', TO_NUMBER('Forms!Form1!Text12')));
```